# How does the Six Apart Update Stream work?

Tags: xml, http, sockets, stream, client-server

Six Apart has this neat service that streams out LiveJournal, Vox, etc. updates:

http://www.sixapart.com/labs/update/developers/

It also has the interesting ability to know if the client has missed parts of the feed.  I've tinkered with writing a similar service for myself, and while I've gotten it to stream okay, I'm ashamed to admit that I not only lack the know-how to check the client but also I lack the proper knowledge to search for how it works.

Could someone tell me what keywords I should use or point me at a tutorial to learn how a streaming web server can know the status of the client?  It may be the case that I'm just misthinking that a browser acts more like a UDP client than TCP in this instance, but any suggestions or explanations would be welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of our infrastructure code is opensource:

Check the plugin that does it all:
http://code.sixapart.com/svn/perlbal/trunk/lib/Perlbal/Plugin/AtomStream.pm

Cheers

Comment: THANK YOU! I didn't even consider that was open source.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be interested in '**[Comet](http://alex.dojotoolkit.org/2006/03/comet-low-latency-data-for-the-browser/)**' [HTTP streaming](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming). Basically the server keeps the connection open to the browser, pushing data (XML, JSON, etc.) to the browser when necessary.

For a Comet server you can check out [cometd](http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/), which provides Comet implementations for a few languages. [Orbited](http://www.orbited.org/) is another server that can do real-time HTTP streaming, written in Python / Twisted.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll be sure to check those out in my research.